# How to remove #2 row from all future columns in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've been trying to find an easy way to do this without going through this manually. Basically I have the following data:

| W01 | W02 | W03 | W04 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| She | She | Boy | Rea |
| Rea | Boy | Rea | Boy |
| Boy | Rea | She | She |
| Mad | Mad | Mel | Bon |
| Mel | Bon | Bon | New |
| Bon | Mel | Cry | Arf |
| The | Ace | New | Gui |
| Cry | Cry | The | Oph |
| Ace | The | Ace | Aty |
| Bab | New | Arf | Buo |

I'm trying to make it so when text enters Row 2 for the first time, it is removed from all future columns and everything else moves up. So it would start by finding "She" in A2 then removing "She" from every future column like so:

| W01 | W02 | W03 | W04 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| She |  | Boy | Rea |
| Rea | Boy | Rea | Boy |
| Boy | Rea |  |  |
| Mad | Mad | Mel | Bon |
| Mel | Bon | Bon | New |
| Bon | Mel | Cry | Arf |
| The | Ace | New | Gui |
| Cry | Cry | The | Oph |
| Ace | The | Ace | Aty |
| Bab | New | Arf | Buo |

Then move everything that's blank up like this:

| W01 | W02 | W03 | W04 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| She | Boy | Boy | Rea |
| Rea | Rea | Rea | Boy |
| Boy | Mad | Mel | Bon |
| Mad | Bon | Bon | New |
| Mel | Mel | Cry | Arf |
| Bon | Ace | New | Gui |
| The | Cry | The | Oph |
| Cry | The | Ace | Aty |
| Ace | New | Arf | Buo |
| Bab | Gat | Bun | Yre |

And then repeat with Column B. So "Boy" is now in Row 2 in B, so remove "Boy" from all columns after B and move up etc etc until it gets to the end (Column AZ).

I was trying to find something with conditional formatting to highlight duplicates or something, but it always flags something as a duplicate *before* it reaches Row 2 for the first time.

Comment: This looks like a job for VBA; I doubt that conditional formatting can handle it.

Comment: y "Bon" is still in W02 & W03 .. ? it is repeated.. right?